Playwright integration with github: [WebServer] Error: supabaseUrl is required
Im'm new to Playwright and I have been struggling with the integration with github.
On the jobs executed on github actions I have the following error after previous jobs are passed:
Run npx playwright test
[WebServer] Error: supabaseUrl is required.
    at new af (/home/runner/work/company-rock-nextjs/company-rock-nextjs/.next/server/chunks/1389.js:1:109082)
    at aw (/home/runner/work/company-rock-nextjs/company-rock-nextjs/.next/server/chunks/1389.js:1:112305)
    at 9206 (/home/runner/work/company-rock-nextjs/company-rock-nextjs/.next/server/chunks/9206.js:1:11529)
    at t (/home/runner/work/company-rock-nextjs/company-rock-nextjs/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 16053 (/home/runner/work/company-rock-nextjs/company-rock-nextjs/.next/server/app/api/company/members/route.js:1:1276)
    at t (/home/runner/work/company-rock-nextjs/company-rock-nextjs/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at r (/home/runner/work/company-rock-nextjs/company-rock-nextjs/.next/server/app/api/company/members/route.js:9:2145)
    at /home/runner/work/company-rock-nextjs/company-rock-nextjs/.next/server/app/api/company/members/route.js:9:2198
    at t.X (/home/runner/work/company-rock-nextjs/company-rock-nextjs/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:1285)
    at /home/runner/work/company-rock-nextjs/company-rock-nextjs/.next/server/app/api/company/members/route.js:9:2158
[WebServer] 
> Build error occurred
[WebServer] Error: Failed to collect page data for /api/company/members
    at /home/runner/work/company-rock-nextjs/company-rock-nextjs/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1258:15
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  type: 'Error'
}

Error: Process from config.webServer was not able to start. Exit code: 1


Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I understand that in playwright.config.ts we have to specify the urls for starting the servers:
/* Run your local dev server before starting the tests */
    webServer:[
  {
     command: 'npm run build && npm run start',
     url: 'http://localhost:3000',
     reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI,
   },
   {
    //I guess something like this:  
    command: 'supabase start',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:54321'
   }
  ],


That is inspired on: [https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testconfig#test-config-web-server]
Thanks

You need to have Supabase running on your GitHub action before you run playwright. Playwright runs your dev server for whatever frontend you're using Nuxt, Vue, Next, Svelte etc, then runs the tests. But you shouldn't use it to run Supabase.
You can achieve what you need by running Supabase in your GitHub action step. I've included the whole workflow that I use as an example. The workflow sets up node and pnpm, then sets Supabase. It then grabs the api url and key from suapabse status and sets them as env variables in an .env file. Then it runs the tests.

name: PR Checks

on:
  pull_request:

jobs:
  install_and_test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: 20

      - name: Use PNPM
        uses: pnpm/action-setup@v4
        with:
          version: 8

      - name: Get pnpm store directory
        shell: bash
        run: |
          echo "STORE_PATH=$(pnpm store path --silent)" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Setup pnpm cache
        uses: actions/cache@v4
        with:
          path: ${{ env.STORE_PATH }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-pnpm-store-${{ hashFiles('**/pnpm-lock.yaml') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-pnpm-store-

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pnpm install
        
      - name: Set up Supabase
        uses: supabase/setup-cli@v1.3.0
      - run: |
        supabase start
        sb_status=$(supabase status)
        api_url=$(echo "$sb_status" | grep -o 'API URL:.*' | awk '{print $3}')
        anon_key=$(echo "$sb_status" | grep -o 'anon key: .*' | awk '{print $3}')
        env_content="SUPABASE_URL=\"$api_url\"\nSUPABASE_ANON_KEY=\"$anon_key\"\n"
        echo -e "$env_content" > .env

      - name: Run e2e Playwright tests
        run: |
          npx playwright install --with-deps
          pnpm test:e2e

Hope that helps
